# openweathermap API can't fetch React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite, openweathermap

I have a problem with my weatherApp, the first API is working and I'm getting all of the data, but I also want to include air pollution but this isn't working, I have the coordinates its asking for but the response I get is nothing to geocode. Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

[image: console.log]

```
function Forecasts() {
    const [data, setData] = useState({});
    const [city, setCity] = useState("");
    const [lat, setLat] = useState("");
    const [lon, setLon] = useState("");
    const [pollution, setPollution] = useState({});
    const apiKey = import.meta.env.VITE_API_KEY;

    const searchLocation = () => {
        // Fetch weather data
        const weatherUrl = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${apiKey}&units=metric`;
        axios.get(weatherUrl)
            .then((response) => {
                setData(response.data);
                setLat(response.data.coord.lat);
                setLon(response.data.coord.lon);
                console.log(response.data);
                console.log(response.data.coord.lat);
                console.log(response.data.coord.lon);

                // Fetch pollution data using coordinates
                const pollutionUrl = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/air_pollution?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&appid=${apiKey}`;
                axios.get(pollutionUrl)
                    .then((pollutionResponse) => {
                        setPollution(pollutionResponse.data);
                        console.log(pollutionResponse.data);
                    })
                    .catch((pollutionError) => {
                        console.error("Error fetching pollution data:", pollutionError);
                    });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error("Error fetching weather data:", error);
            });

        setCity("");
    }
```

I'm clueless at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Thе issuе you arе facing is rеlatеd to thе timing of thе `lat` and `lon` variablеs you arе trying to usе thе `lat` and `lon` valuеs to construct thе URL for fеtching air pollution data immеdiatеly aftеr calling `sеtLat` and `sеtLon` thе statе updatеs arе asynchronous so thе valuеs of `lat` and `lon` may not havе bееn updatеd yеt whеn you usе thеm to construct thе pollutionUrl this is why you arе gеtting thе "nothing to gеocodе" еrror

Comment: if u mean i should make it async await then it doesnt solve it already tried that out

Comment: Try not nesting the requests and try creating variables for the lat and lon for the API to use.

Comment: thanks making varriables out of the lat and lon did fix the whole thing :)

Answer (score 0):

Setting state in react js is asynchronous. You are using setLat() and setLon(), which are asynchronous here. At the time of second api call both the states are empty. Instead try below:

```
function Forecasts() {
    const [data, setData] = useState({});
    const [city, setCity] = useState("");
    const [lat, setLat] = useState("");
    const [lon, setLon] = useState("");
    const [pollution, setPollution] = useState({});
    const apiKey = import.meta.env.VITE_API_KEY;

    const searchLocation = () => {
        // Fetch weather data
        const weatherUrl = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${apiKey}&units=metric`;
        axios.get(weatherUrl)
            .then((response) => {
                setData(response.data);
        const latitude =response.data.coord.lat;

        const longitude =response.data.coord.lon;     
  
        setLat(latitude);
                    
        setLon(longitude );
                    console.log(response.data);
                    console.log(response.data.coord.lat);
                    console.log(response.data.coord.lon);
    
                    // Fetch pollution data using coordinates
                    const pollutionUrl = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/air_pollution?lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&appid=${apiKey}`;
                    axios.get(pollutionUrl)
                        .then((pollutionResponse) => {
                            setPollution(pollutionResponse.data);
                            console.log(pollutionResponse.data);
                        })
                        .catch((pollutionError) => {
                            console.error("Error fetching pollution data:", pollutionError);
                        });
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error("Error fetching weather data:", error);
                });
    
            setCity("");
        }
```